# Geth. How to read the value of a public variable?

Tags: go-ethereum

How do I read the value of a public property ("count") in my contract using Geth?

Solidity:

```
contract Core {

    address public owner;
    uint public count;
    uint public tax;
    event NewMarketLog(address market, address owner);
    mapping (address=>address) public MarketplaceList;

    function Core (){
        owner=msg.sender;
    }

    function CreateMarketplace (string _name, string _desc, string _telegram)  returns (address) {
        count++;
        address adr=new Marketplace(_name,_desc,_telegram,msg.sender);
        NewMarketLog(adr, msg.sender);
    return  MarketplaceList[msg.sender]=  adr;
    }
}
```

Comment: as the variable is public it doesn't need a getter but what do you mean exactly by read the value using geth?

Comment: I want to read this variable. Like that : Var Core = eth.contract (contract.info.abiDefinition); Var MyCore = Core .at (address); MyCore .count.call () => * Count (value) *